# Accessing a hash element inside of an array

Tags: ruby, twitter, hash

The gem 'twitter' I am using is providing me the following results when I attempt to run the following method:

```
def timeline
    @mytimeline = Twitter.user_timeline("cnn")
    newstring = @mytimeline.to_s
    puts newstring
  end

#<Twitter::Tweet:0x00000001647390>                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#<Twitter::Tweet:0x00000001647368>                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#<Twitter::Tweet:0x00000001647340> 
...
```

I am trying to access the results via the hash symbol.

When I convert .to_s I can get a huge dump of the entire hash but in a string...

What is the easiest way that I can access the symbols? Here are the results I get:

```
[#<Twitter::Tweet:0x0000000210ba88 
@attrs={
:created_at=>"Thu Sep 19 17:01:56 +0000 2013", 
:id=>380738540914479104, 
:id_str=>"380738540914479104", 
:text=>"What if you could buy a smartphone that would last you for the rest of your life? http://t.co/3j5N9gz18H", 
:source=>"web", 
:truncated=>false, 
:in_reply_to_status_id=>nil, 
:in_reply_to_status_id_str=>nil,
...
}
```

Comment: What data are you trying to get at? Printing the entire Tweet object or just the tweet data? It seems as if you're looking to iterate over the Collection of Tweets.

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to call any specific hash symbol and do whatever I want with the data. For example: If i create a new tweet , i want to be able to then do a call to find out the twitter URL for that new generated tweet.

Comment: `@mytimeline` is an array of Tweet objects. So if you want the `text` of first tweet, use `@mytimeline.first.text`. To get an array of all `text` , use `@mytimeline.map(&:text)` and so on ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with a [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html) of [Tweet](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Tweet)s.

You can access a certain symbol in each [Tweet](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Tweet) by iterating through the [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html):

```
@mytimeline.each { |tweet| print tweet[:text] }
```

Comment: Heh, I attempted this earlier, atleast I thought so :) Anyway its good now. That is what I needed to movre forward.

Comment: No problem. Read up on Arrays and Hashes in Ruby and how to iterate through them and get the meat and potatoes.

Comment: Yeah i have been reading up on them. For somereason I was over complicating something so simple :)